# YesNo Button Click Handlers on DialogFragment [Mono for Android]

Tags: android, mono, fragment, android-alertdialog, dialogfragment

I have a ListFragment that has checkboxes on it...

```
public class ViewOrderLineFragment : ListFragment {
      public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item){
            switch (item.TitleFormatted.ToString()){
                case "Add":
                   //stuff here
                    break;
                case "Edit":
                        var dialog = new ConfirmationFragment(Activity);
                        dialog.Show(FragmentManager, null);
                    break;
            }

            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
       public void DoPositiveClick(){=
           DeletedSelectedItems();=
        }

        public void DoNegativeClick()={
            // Do stuff here.
            //Log.Info("FragmentAlertDialog", "Negative click!");
        }

        void DeletedSelectedItems={
           //do stuff here
         }
}
```

When I select some items and press the delete button, it will prompt the user "R u sure ?"

Here is my code for the DialogFragment.

```
public class ConfirmationFragment : DialogFragment { 
Context _context;
        public ConfirmationFragment(Context context) {
            _context = context;   
        }
public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedState){
 return new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity)
                //.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                //.SetTitle(title)
            .SetPositiveButton("Yes", (sender, e) =>
            {
                ((ViewOrderLineFragment)Activity).DoPositiveClick();
            })
            .SetNegativeButton("No", (sender, e) =>
            {
                ((ViewOrderLineFragment)Activity).DoNegativeClick();
            }).Create();
        }
}
```

Error:
`Cannot convert type 'Android.App.Activity' to 'OTCMobile.Screens.ViewOrderLineFragment'`

On line `((ViewOrderLineFragment)Activity).DoPositiveClick();`

I followed this sample [this link](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/Support4/Support4/Activities/FragmentAlertDialogSupport.cs)

Any alternate solutions ?

Comment: If `ViewOrderLineFragment` is a `Fragment` you can't cast it to an `Activity`. Perhaps post a code snippet of `ViewOrderOnlineFragment`.

Comment: try this:
((FragmentActivity)Activity).DoPositiveClick();

Comment: Please notice the formatting changes made. Useless empty lines make it annoying to read. Please keep your question neat and Capitalized and recheck your grammar.

Answer (score 0):

I scrapped out the ConfirmationFragment..

This worked for me.

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item) {
        switch (item.TitleFormatted.ToString()) {
            case "Add":
               //some stuff
                break;
            case "Edit":
              var confirmDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.Activity)
                        //.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                        .SetTitle("Are you sure you want to delete all selected?")
                    .SetPositiveButton("Yes", (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        DoPositiveClick();
                    })
                    .SetNegativeButton("No", (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        DoNegativeClick();
                    }).Create();
                    confirmDialog.Show();

                }
                break;
        }
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```